# Why is the velocity potential (in fluids) multi-valued in non-simply connected domains?

Tags: connectedness, fluid-dynamics, stokes-theorem, potential-theory

In Fluid Mechanics, you can define a velocity potential as a closed line integral in a vector field, which equals the sum of curl (vorticity) inside the line over which you are integrating (by Stokes' Theorem).

But if there's a singularity (or it's a non-simply connected domain), you get that the velocity potential is (can be?) multi-valued.

Is there a way to understand how this happens without Complex Analysis? How does the 'singularity' inside the domain make the line integral multi-valued? Is there something in Stokes' theorem that I am skimming over?

Comment: I think you have something mixed up. The integral of vorticity over the area enclosed by a closed loop is the circulation, not the velocity potential. Can you double-check the definition of the velocity potential?

Comment: If you take the derivative of that line integral, you get the velocity, so it is a velocity potential function.